# Flatten multiple nested arrays on BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have several columns which nested arrays in bigquery table which looked like:

```
marketing_table
+------+------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
|Row   | effective_status | targeting.age_min| targeting.audience_network_positions.value | targeting.facebook_positions.value | targeting.instagram_positions.value | campaign_id |
+------+------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
|    1 |  Active          |      22          |                classic                     |       feed                         |                 stream              |     1       |
|      |                  |                  |                instream video              |       video_feeds                  |                 story               |             |     
|      |                  |                  |                                            |       instant_article              |                 explore             |             |   
|      |                  |                  |                                            |       instream_video               |                                     |             | 
|      |                  |                  |                                            |       marketplace                  |                                     |             | 
|      |                  |                  |                                            |       story                        |                                     |             |   
|    2 |  WITH_ISSUES     |      22          |                classic                     |       feed                         |                 stream              |     1       |
|      |                  |                  |                instream video              |       video_feeds                  |                 story               |             |     
|      |                  |                  |                                            |       instant_article              |                 explore             |             |   
|      |                  |                  |                                            |       instream_video               |                                     |             | 
|      |                  |                  |                                            |       marketplace                  |                                     |             | 
|      |                  |                  |                                            |       story                        |                                     |             |   
+------+------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
```

The SQL scheme is look like:

```
Field name, Type, Mode
----------------------- 
effective_status, STRING, NULLABLE
targeting. age_min, INTEGER, NULLABLE
targeting. age_min, INTEGER, NULLABLE
targeting.audience_network_positions.value, RECORD, REPEATED
targeting. facebook_positions, RECORD, REPEATED
targeting.facebook_positions.value, STRING, NULLABLE
targeting. instagram_positions, RECORD, REPEATED
targeting.instagram_positions.value, STRING, NULLABLE
campaign_id, STRING, NULLABLE
```

I want it to flatten all the nested array, so they produce

```
marketing_table
+------+------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
|Row   | effective_status | targeting.age_min| targeting.audience_network_positions.value | targeting.facebook_positions.value | targeting.instagram_positions.value | campaign_id |
+------+------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
|    1 |  Active          |      22          |                classic                     |       feed                         |                 stream              |     1       |
|    2 |  Active          |      22          |                instream video              |       video_feeds                  |                 story               |     1       |     
|    3 |  Active          |      22          |                instream video              |       instant_article              |                 explore             |     1       |   
|    4 |  Active          |      22          |                instream video              |       instream_video               |                 explore             |     1       | 
|    5 |  Active          |      22          |                instream video              |       marketplace                  |                 explore             |     1       | 
|    6 |  Active          |      22          |                instream video              |       story                        |                 explore             |     1       |   
|    7 |  WITH_ISSUES     |      22          |                classic                     |       feed                         |                 stream              |     1       |
|    8 |  WITH_ISSUES     |      22          |                instream video              |       video_feeds                  |                 story               |     1       |     
|    9 |  WITH_ISSUES     |      22          |                instream video              |       instant_article              |                 explore             |     1       |   
|    10|  WITH_ISSUES     |      22          |                instream video              |       instream_video               |                 explore             |     1       | 
|    11|  WITH_ISSUES     |      22          |                instream video              |       marketplace                  |                 explore             |     1       | 
|    12|  WITH_ISSUES     |      22          |                instream video              |       story                        |                 explore             |     1       |   
+------+------------------+------------------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+-------------+
```

Could you guys show me how to properly unnest all those arrays using the `unnest` argument on bigquery SQL?

Comment: Could you show the structure of your table? The expected result for the `targeting.instagram_positions.value` column looks a bit strange...

Comment: @SergeyGeron I have updated my question, please take a look sir

Answer (score 2):

something like this should work.

```
select 
t.effective_status, 
t.targeting.age_min,
anp.value as anp_value,
fp.value as fp_value,
ip.value as ip_value,
t.campaign_id

from table t, 
unnest(t.targeting.audience_network_positions) as anp, 
unnest(t.targeting.facebook_positions) fp, 
unnest(t.instagram_positions) as ip
```